# Comparsion between friend-of-friend-of-friend-of... relationships in MySQL and Neo4J

Tags: mysql, graph, neo4j, gremlin

To see the advantages of using Neo4J for friend-relationships, i created on MySQL database with one table for the Persons ("Persons", 20900 datasets):

```
id     | name
--------------
 1     | Peter
 2     | Max
 3     | Sam
 ...   | ...
 20900 | Rudi
```

and one table for the relationships ("Friendships", each person with 50 to 100 friends):

```
personen_id_1 | personen_id_2
-------------------------
 1         | 2
 1         | 3
 2         | 56
 ...       | ...
 20900     | 201
```

so, there are arround 1.2 million relationships.

Now i want to now the friends-of-friends-of-friends-of-friends of Person with id=1, so i crafted a query like this:

```
select distinct P.name
from Friendships f
join Friendships f2 ON f.personen_id_2 = f2.personen_id_1
join Friendships f3 ON f2.personen_id_2 = f3.personen_id_1
join Friendships f4 ON f3.personen_id_2 = f4.personen_id_1
join Persons P ON f4.personen_id_2 = P.id
where f.personen_id_1 = 1
```

the query took arround 30 seconds for user-id 1

In Neo4J i created for each person one Node (20900 Nodes) with one name-property. All nodes were connected equal to the Friendships-table in MySQL, so there are 1.2 million relationships.

to get the same frinedset here, i typed in gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.inV.loop(2){ it.loops <= 4 }.name.dedup.map()
```

this took arround 1 minute. I dont expected this at all!

so is my comparsion correct? and if yes, how to modify this example to show the advantages of using neo4j for this task?

Comment: What JVM setup did you use? And what is your hardware? The default memory settings for a JVM are much too small for a database. If this is the first run, it will just measure your disk speed to pull in the data.

Comment: i use oracle jvm 1.6 with the heap-size set to `java -Xms 1G -Xmx 1G`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly familiar with Gremlin, but I generated a similar sized dataset (stats below) and ran an equivalent query in Cypher:

```
START person=node:user(name={name})
MATCH person-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-friend
RETURN friend.name AS name
```

I ran this 1000 times against the dataset, each time picking a different user as the starting point. I didn't warm the cache before running the  tests, so this was from a standing start. Average response time: 33 ms.

Running on a MacBook Pro, 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 GB RAM, 4 GB heap

Here are the graph stats:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| user           | 20900                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                | Average |    High |     Low |
+----------------------------------------------+
| FRIEND                                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
|       OUTGOING |      74 |     100 |      48 |
|       incoming |      74 |     123 |      31 |
+----------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------+
| _UNKNOWN       | 1                           |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                | Average |    High |     Low |
+----------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------+
| Totals                                       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| Nodes          | 20901                       |
| Relationships  | 1565787                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
| FRIEND         | 1565787                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: my specs: Corei5 2.5GHz, 8GB Ram, 2GB Java Heap-size. After increasing the RAM-size for memeory-io mapping of nodes and relationships, e.g. `neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1000M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1000M` the query took 30 seconds, still too long

Comment: the cypher query is as slow as the one in gremlin

Comment: With your dataset, at depth 4, everybody is likely connected to everybody else. If each person has exactly 100 friends, then a depth 4 search will traverse 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 relationships, which is 100,000,000 traversals, or 100,000,000 entities visited. On commodity hardware, Neo4j can typically traverse 1-2 million relationships per second - that is, 1-2 million joins per second. So the numbers add up. If this were a real domain, we'd probably only want the first 100 or 1000 people at depth 4: if you iterate the result 100 times, you'll get the low ms response.

Comment: can you give an example for getting only the 100 first nodes of a depth 4 search in gremlin?

Comment: In Cypher, this looks like `START person=node:user(name={name})
MATCH person-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-friend
RETURN friend.name AS name LIMIT 100`, be sure to use Neo4j 1.9.M02 for this as there are some major optimisations around this done.

Comment: okay, thats quite fast, arround 100ms with warm cache, but mysql is even faster when limiting the resultset to 100: ~ 2ms

Answer (score 1):

If you know you are doing 4 loops, do this:

```
g.v(1).out.out.out.out.name.dedup.map
```

There is a known semantic bug in Gremlin where loop() will turn into a breadth-first query.
   https://github.com/tinkerpop/pipes/issues/25

Moreover, don't do outE.inV if you don't need to. The equivalent is out. Also, realize you are doing a 4 step search, that is a massive computation (combinatorial explosion). This is something that graph databases are not good at. You will want to look at a batch analytics framework like Faunus for this -- http://thinkaurelius.github.com/faunus/. For a reason why, see http://thinkaurelius.com/2012/04/21/loopy-lattices/

Graph databases are optimized for local traversals, by 4 steps, you touched (most likely) your entire dataset and using a "get get get"-style of database access, this is not efficient.

HTH,
Marko.

Comment: okay, but i thought this should be more efficient than the same szenario in mysql?!